# Arabic data not shown while export to PDF

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports

I am designed a report using *JasperReports Server 5.5.0*. In my report's data contains text on Arabic as well as on English. The English shows normally but Arabic data not displayed while export to pdf. It work fine when I export to html. What necessary setting required to do that stub?

Comment: Did you use the [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)?

Comment: Thank u Alex yes i use  the font extension it gives error when i publish to jasper server and export as pdf. error is Error Message

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font : pdfFontName : Helvetica pdfEncoding : Identity-H isPdfEmbedded : true

Comment: @Ravi if you are using windows machine u can use the arial.ttf font with encoding Identity-H.it works for arabic

Comment: Thanks amudhan3093 it works,need to install font in jasper server as well as followed the steps as you commented